# Custom toolbar and search bar in MKMapView

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview, toolbar

How can I load default mapview toolbar and search bar in Iphone when I am loading mkmapview from my viewcontroller class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get the search toolbar which you called default and the reason is that Map Application that's developed by Apple may have both (search toolbar and mapview ) separated with each others.

So, would suggest you to use both as the separate views.

`myCustomSearchToolBar` can be either the instance of your Custom search bar view Or `UISearchBar`.

```
[containerView addSubview:myCustomSearchToolBar];
[containerView addSubview:myMapView];
[self.view addSubview:containerView];
```

Go through the below blog post for creating UISearchBar.

[Building a SearchView with UISearchBar and UITableView](http://jduff.github.com/2010/03/01/building-a-searchview-with-uisearchbar-and-uitableview/)

Comment: I want default toolbar that we see when we load mapview from Iphone. Do I have to create an extra view and create a custom toolbar in it Or is it available in sdk?

Comment: @John Valiaveettil : i could not get you, would you explain ?

Comment: When we load  maps app in Iphone, we see a toolbar in the mapview with buttons "search" and "direction". I was referring to the same. I need to create that in my app. How could I do that?

Comment: @John Valiaveettil : I get you now ... check the edited answer.

Comment: Thats a good example on search bar. But I am still unclear about the toolbar.